# Is this patent deemed abandoned?

Tags: application, abandoned-patent

In reference to the patent: [EP2760362A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2760362A1)
Hi. I note there has been over 4 years since this patent was filed (5 years since its priority date) and it is still down as an "Application". Does this mean it is effectively past its deadline and can no longer be granted?

Answer (score 2):

This patent application is still active, although substantive examination has not started yet. In fact the renewal fees were paid in April 2016 (so it will definitely be active till April 2017). As long as it is not granted, it remains an application.
As far as it concerns the EPO there is no time limit within which a patent must be granted. I am quite sure there is no provision in other major patent offices as well.